# how to get day difference between current date with dates stored in firebase firebase and display the result in an html table

Tags: javascript

I am retrieving a firebase collection using JavaScriptjaca and intend to get the difference between the current date and dates stored in the returned collection.

```
 this.firebaseSrvc.function().subscribe((data)=>{
             data.forEach(e =>{ 
    const x = new Date(e.dataPagamento).toLocaleDateString();
    const y = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    const a = Math.abs(new Date(y).valueOf() - new Date(x).valueOf());
    const b = Math.ceil(a/(1000*60*60*24));
    this.dates = b;
});
});
```

After that I want to populate an html table with **"this.dates"**, but only appears the last item

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col id="b">{{dates}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

I need help on how to fill the table with all this.dates values

Comment: Because you keep overwriting the value of `this.dates`. You expect `this.dates` to hold multiple values like an `Array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Store the result in an array, not in a single number.

Try this:

```
this.firebaseSrvc.function().subscribe(
  (data)=>{
    this.dates = []; // <---- Create an empty array
    data.forEach(e =>{ 
      const x = new Date(e.dataPagamento).toLocaleDateString();
      const y = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
      const a = Math.abs(new Date(y).valueOf() - new Date(x).valueOf());
      const b = Math.ceil(a/(1000*60*60*24));
      this.dates.push(b);  // <---- Push each result as a new entry in the array
  });
});
```

#### Display the array using a `for` loop

For example, if you are using Ionic Vue:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col  v-for="date in dates">{{date}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much  ProfDFrancis. I just had to do the following  in html: <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>{{dates[i]}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>